# pip install package isn't working, suggests libxml2, libxslt not installed but they are?

Tags: python, xml, windows, xslt, pip

I am trying to install the footprintsapi package: https://pypi.org/project/footprintsapi/

Python version 3.8.5. I am using Anaconda on a Windows 10 work computer, which means sometimes I can install things on my own, sometimes I have to go through a remote session with IT, and they don't seem to understand anything related to python packages. I don't really understand why I can install some things on my own and others not, all my other work has been on my personal Mac.

When I try to run pip install footprintsapi I get the following:

```
  Using cached footprintsapi-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi~=2019.3.9 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate~=0.6.0 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3~=1.24.3 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet~=3.0.4 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna~=2.8 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.12.0 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property~=1.5.1 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml~=0.6.0 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zeep~=3.3.1 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs~=1.4.3 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz~=2019.1 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs~=19.1.0 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests~=2.21.0 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt~=0.9.1 in c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from footprintsapi) (0.9.1)
Collecting lxml~=4.3.3
  Using cached lxml-4.3.5.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-c3fraqkv'
       cwd: C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b4buy16q\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\
  Complete output (97 lines):
  Building lxml version 4.3.5.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\lxml
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
  etree.c
  C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b4buy16q\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  creating Users
  creating Users\mrb716
  creating Users\mrb716\AppData
  creating Users\mrb716\AppData\Local
  creating Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitplpghzwh.c /FoUsers\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitplpghzwh.obj
  xmlXPathInitplpghzwh.c
  C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitplpghzwh.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, footprintsapi
  Attempting uninstall: lxml
    Found existing installation: lxml 4.6.3
    Uninstalling lxml-4.6.3:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml-4.6.3
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-n24q03jt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\Include\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b4buy16q\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\
    Complete output (92 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    etree.c
    C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b4buy16q\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitgmqh3y4v.c /FoUsers\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitgmqh3y4v.obj
    xmlXPathInitgmqh3y4v.c
    C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitgmqh3y4v.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml
  Moving to c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml-4.6.3.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\mrb716\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~xml-4.6.3.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml\
   from C:\Users\mrb716\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~xml
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mrb716\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b4buy16q\\lxml_125a9403a5f841198be8b7308a743ba9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mrb716\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-n24q03jt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mrb716\anaconda3\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have double checked that lxml is installed, which includes libxml2 and libxslt. I've tried installing it using both anaconda and from the unofficial binaries with no problems, but I still get these errors when I try to install footprintsapi. Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

OK I think the problem came down to the pip version needing lxml 4.3.5 which is incompatible with my version of python? The most recent version of footprintsapi on github is updated to use lxml 4.6.3. I'm not sure if this was the root issue, but what did work was to install from github using `pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Jesus-E-Rodriguez/footprintsapi/tarball/master`